Adding thick underline behind text while maintaining text behaviour
I'm trying to add a thick custom underline behind the text without breaking the text wrapping behaviour. Something like below screenshot.

But I'm running into problems. I've tried two approaches

Using a CustomPainter on a TextSpan to paint the decoration.
Problem: Can pair it with other text spans but it doesn't handle line breaks correctly.

Using background property on TextStyle with Paint() and shader. The line breaks work fine here.
Problem: This behaves weird when scrolling.
Video demo - https://imgur.com/lO0OHrX


Is there a different approach I can take here? I'd want to keep the line-breaking properties and scroll behaviour intact while being able to highlight only certain parts of the text. Thanks for your time!
class UnderlineText extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnderlineText({super.key});

  static const data1 = 'This is un-highlighted text';
  static const data2 = ' and this is a very long highlighted text to test if '
      'highlight would wrap itself when text folds.';

  static const data3 = "Ascent is the font's spacing above the baseline "
      "without leading and descent is the spacing below the baseline without "
      "leading. Leading is split evenly between the top and bottom. The values "
      "for ascent and descent are provided by the font named by fontFamily.";

  static const data4 =
      " If no fontFamily or fontFamilyFallback is provided, then the platform's "
      "default family will be used. Many fonts will have leading values of zero, "
      "so in practice, the leading component is often irrelevant.";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final font = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium;

    final fontSize =
        (Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium?.fontSize ?? 0) *
            (Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium?.height ?? 1);

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: font,
        children: [
          TextSpan(text: data1),
          TextSpan(
            text: data2 + data3,
            style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()
                ..shader = LinearGradient(
                  colors: <Color>[
                    Colors.transparent,
                    Colors.red,
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
                  stops: [0.75, 0.75],
                ).createShader(
                  Rect.fromLTWH(
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    fontSize,
                  ),
                ),
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(text: data4),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I have tried your given code and the output is https://prnt.sc/ZQI4nZA0u9_7.
What do you need further?

It doesn't behave correctly while scrolling. Let me add a recording as well.

I've added the video representation of the issue - https://imgur.com/lO0OHrX

Added code for this issue. Hope it helps...

Try below code
return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            style: font,
            children: [
              TextSpan(text: data1),
              TextSpan(
                text: data2 + data3,
                style: TextStyle(
                  background: Paint()
                    ..shader = LinearGradient(
                      colors: <Color>[
                        Colors.transparent,
                        Colors.red,
                      ],
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
                      stops: [
                        0.75,
                        0.75,
                      ],
                    ).createShader(
                      Rect.fromLTWH(
                        0,
                        0,
                        MediaQuery.of(context)
                            .size
                            .width, // Use width of the screen
                        fontSize,
                      ),
                    ),
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(text: data4),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


Thanks a lot!. I just had to wrap this in a LayoutBuilder and replace the screen width params with constraints.maxWidth to make this work for all texts.

Hi, this works but I'm having a hard time trying to understand how adding a scrollview is fixing this issue. Can you please help me understand your thought process and how you arrived to this solution?

As you commented it doesn't behave properly when scrolling, so I tried with SingleChildScrollView.
